# Facebook Places API Requires Token? Documentation Implies It Doesn't

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On the Facebook Graph API, the documentation is worded as if the API can be queried without an OAUTH token for places based on radius or category.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/overview

If a request is performed to query social-related information, the API call would require a token.

I don't want to use a token for my request as I just want to query all restaurants near the specified city name. This query will be embedded into a web-app used by others, and I don't want a token to be used.

My question is: is it possible to search for places based on the location without a token? It seems to me that this is possible based on the documentation on the graph API, but everything I try returns the response:

error
message "An access token is required to request this resource."
type    "OAuthException"
code    104
fbtrace_id  "{ID is generated}"

The query I am performing is simple:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/search?type=place&center=40.7304,-73.9921&distance=1000

I would appreciate any help with this.

Rusty

Comment: The documentation say nothing about not needing a token. It say if you have a user access token ... So it just means that you can use other types of access tokens like page or app. It doesn't mean you don't need one